# VBA: Compare two record sets and return records that are available in record set 1 and not available in record set 2

Tags: excel, vba, macros, adodb

I am trying to run a query through excel macro, fetching data from two tables. And I would like to compare both the table for difference. I have two record set each with close to 100 columns. I need to compare both the record set and return the mismatch records. With below conditions,

1. Column names are dynamic and cannot be defined static
2. Number of Columns may differ based on the Query we have been passing
3. The Record count may be more and we should not copy the complete record set to any of the excel sheet

Through the below code, I am generating record set. Could anyone help me out in comparing this record sets without defining the columns(i.e., I need to compare the full record and not column by column)

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim sql As String


sConnString = "Provider=ASEOLEDB;Data Source=<Servername> Initial Catalog=<DB Name>;User Id=<UserID> Password=<Pwd>"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString
If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
MsgBox ("Success")
End If

Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table1;")
Set rs1 = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table2;")
rs.Close
rs1.Close
conn.Close
```

Comment: It seems that you have a working DB server which is capable of handling SQL queries. So, why are you trying to do in Excel (using VBA) what a DB server is destined to do (faster and more efficiently)?

Comment: Good Question..! The above is an sample code. What I was actually trying to do is pull out data from two tables one is from Sql server and other from Sybase and trying to compare both. More or less, its like validating the data migrated. I couldn't add or modify servers in my work systems and the simpler way I can think about is using a VBA. Hope you could get me a solution.

Comment: Setup a [linked-server connection between the SQL Server and the Sybase Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280102) and then do the comparison there using SQL.

Comment: Good one..! But I cannot make linked server connection as I am restricted to do so in my client system. I have tried all possible solutions through SQL and after all the analysis I made my way out of it and trying with external app/tool.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  I'm sure you CAN do this in Excel, but why bother?  Just run the Access 'find unmatched query wizard'.  See the link below for a short demo on how it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lktivZpKutc